# Blazor on server-side: using MongoDB for Identity management

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

The Asp.Net Core Blazor template in VS 2019 can create a server-side app that will use the Microsoft SQL Server to manage the accounts and claims for identity management.

I would like to use **MongoDB** instead for account and claims management. This way I want to enable Blazor to use decorators and AuthorizeView to allow specific access for specific identities or claims.

I have scaffolded the Identity construct but I am confused how to proceed.

There is an open source Identity provider available called **AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo**.

Can I use this provider with blazor and if so how can I integrate this provider into my Blazor project?

Is there any project on github that will demonstrate the necessary adjustments in Blazor for custom identity providers?

Comment: Please check this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am looking at doing Similar. Blazor essentially uses Dotnet core, So solutions relevent to that can be implemented.

The relevant Nugetpackage is https://github.com/matteofabbri/AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo/blob/master/README.md
For 3.0 use Nuget packages of the 6 series ( latest 6.7 )

Here is a github Example that I found which uses momgoDb as the database for Identity.
https://github.com/AlejandroRuiz/CosmosDBTutorial

The Git Hub is the implementation of this Tutorial.
[enter link description here](http://alejandroruizvarela.blogspot.com/2018/11/aspnet-core-identity-with-cosmos-db.html)